# Storing filepath and size in C++

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, unordered-map

I'm processing a large number of image files (tens of millions) and I need to return the number of pixels for each file.

I have a function that uses an `std::map<string, unsigned int>` to keep track of files already processed. If a path is found in the map, then the value is returned, otherwise the file is processed and inserted into the map. I do not delete entries from the map.

The problem is as the number of entries grow, the time for lookup is killing the performance. This portion of my application is single threaded.

I wanted to know if `unordered_map` is the solution to this, or the fact that I'm using `std::string` as keys going to affects the hashing and require too many rehashings as the number of keys increases, thus once again killing the performance.

One other item to note is that the paths for the string are expected (but not guaranteed) to have the same prefix, for example: `/common/until/here/now_different/`. So all strings will likely have the same first N characters. I could potentially store these as relative to the common directory. How likely is that to help performance?

Comment: Is it difficult to try `unordered_map` and see the difference? You could also try a reverse comparator for the strings if the tail end varies the most.

Comment: @Galik I'm running the `unordered_map` test (takes a few hours). But given what I have read elsewhere, I don't expect there to be an improvement.
The reverse comparator is certainly a good idea to try. Thanks!

Comment: Your question has no direct answer and you will have to profile it; it is fair to assume that std::map is less efficient in this case, but it's no guarantee. A hash-map might be a good solution, but then you also need to think about how the hashing is done. Test and measure.

Comment: Unless you need to iterate through the list of paths in order, I think `unordered_map` should work better for you. You can construct it with a large number of preallocated buckets and set a proper [`max_load_factor()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/max_load_factor), just but be careful with the [`max_bucket_count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/max_bucket_count).

Comment: Just wondering - how come you're hitting repeated files?  Maybe there's a way to prevent that completely?

Comment: @UKMonkey The query for size is coming from objects that can use the same files.

Comment: Also you could try using [std::filesystem::path](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) as your key rather than `std::string` as obtaining a `hash` for it may be optimized better for filenames. Or, further, you could use some native representation (like an `inode` value for your key) which might be very efficient to compare.

Comment: @Galik The C++ standard (at least at C++14 with experimental filesystem) does not provide a hash function for map. So I think that's not going to work.

Comment: @shehzan Ah, well `C++17` has it (as does my version of experimental filesystem in `GCC 7.3`) so I thought it was worth a mention.

Answer (score 0):

`unordered_map` will probably be better in this case. It will typically be implemented as a hash table, with amortized O(1) lookup time, while `map` is usually a binary tree with O(log n) lookups. It doesn't sound like your application would care about the order of items in the map, it's just a simple lookup table.

In both cases, removing the common prefix should be helpful, as it means less time has to be spent needlessly iterating over that part of the strings. For `unordered_map` it will have to traverse it twice: once to hash and then to compare against the keys in the table. Some hash functions also limit the amount of a string they hash, to prevent O(n) hash performance -- if the common prefix is longer than this limit, you'll end up with a worst-case hash table (everything is in one bucket).

Answer (score 0):

I really like Galik's suggestion of using inodes if you can, but if not...

Will emphasise a point already made in comments: ***if you've reason to care, always implement the alternatives and measure***.  The more reason, the more effort it's worth expending on that....

So /- another option is to use a 128-bit cryptographic strength hash function on your filepaths, then trust that statistically it's *extremely* unlikely to produce a collision.  A rule of thumb is that if you have 2^n distinct keys, you want *significantly* more than a 2n-bit hash.  For ~100m keys, that's about 2*27 bits, so you could probably get away with a 64 bit hash but it's a little too close for comfort and headroom if the number of images grows over the years.  Then use a vector to back a hash table of *just* the hashes and file sizes, with say quadratic probing.  Your caller would ideally pre-calculate the hash of an incoming file path in a different thread, passing your lookup API only the hash.

The above avoids the dynamic memory allocation, indirection, and of course memory usage when storing variable-length strings in the hash table and utilises the cache much better.  Relying on hashes not colliding may make you uncomfortable, but past a point the odds of a meteor destroying the computer, or lightning frying it, will be higher than the odds of a collision in the hash space (i.e. *before* mapping to hash table bucket), so there's really no point fixating on that.  Cryptographic hashing is relatively slow, hence the suggestion to let clients do it in other threads.

(I have worked with a proprietary distributed database based on exactly this principle for path-like keys.)

Aside: beware Visual C++'s string hashing - they pick 10 characters spaced along your string to incorporate in the hash value, which would be extremely collision prone for you, especially if several of those were taken from the common prefix.  The C++ Standard leaves implementations the freedom to provide whatever hashes they like, so re-measure such things if you ever need to port your system.